# ¿Como usar en el cliente una propiedad de tipo System.type en una clase que serializo por WCF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net

Tengo la siguiente clase definida en un Web Service WCF:

```
[DataContract]
public class cFiltro
{
    [DataMember]
    public string columna { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public Type tipo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string valor { get; set; }

    public cFiltro()
    {

    }
}
```

El problema viene cuando desde un cliente intento crear un objeto de la clase, al asignar un valor a la propiedad "tipo" no me deja, me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

> Error 1   No se puede convertir implícitamente el tipo 'System.Type' en
>   'MINAMESPACE.wsentradas.Type'

El código donde realizo la asignación es el siguiente:

```
cFiltro filtro = new cFiltro();
filtro.tipo = typeof(Int32);
```

Como se puede ver lo que quiero es asignar el tipo Int32 a dicha propiedad, pero no puedo. ¿Alguna idea?

El uso de la propiedad tipo es guardar el tipo que es la propiedad valor, por ejemplo:

tipo: int

valor: 123

Comment: Cual es el uso de la propiedad tipo, porque parece se parte de un valor que se guardara en tablas, por lo que se puede cambiar type por string nombreTipo

Comment: @MiguelZarate he editado con respecto al uso. Y no, tanto el cliente como el servicio son .net, misma versión de framework y ademas en c#.

Comment: No se puede enviar Type por WCF debido a que es un generico y los genericos no se pueden establecer en WCF. Esto porque no solo es la definicion del tipo en la clase sino que tambien es posible enviar dichos objetos serializados, para enviar la serializacion un objeto debe estar definido, para el caso de Type puede ser cualquier cosa Int, string, Sream, . Para tu caso de ejemplo que te parece nombreTipo="int32"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es lo que agregue en mi ultimo comentario:

No se puede enviar Type por WCF debido a que es un generico y los genericos no se pueden establecer en WCF. Esto porque no solo es la definicion del tipo en la clase sino que tambien es posible enviar dichos objetos serializados, para enviar la serializacion un objeto debe estar definido, para el caso de Type puede ser cualquier cosa Int, string, Sream, . Para tu caso de ejemplo que te parece nombreTipo="int32"

Ahora usando la declaracion del objeto:

```
[DataContract]
public class cFiltro
{
    [DataMember]
    public string columna { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string NombreTipo { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string valor { get; set; }


}
```

Es posible que se cree una instancia apartir de las propiedades establecidas

```
cFiltro filtro = new cFiltro();
filtro.NombreTipo= "Int32";
filtro.Valor="132";

//esto es pseudo codigo no tengo un compilador a la mano pero te dara una idea
//de como crear la instancia y asignarle valor.

 var filtroInstancia= ObtenerInstancia(filtro.NombreTipo);

if(filtroInstancia !=null)
{
  TryParse(filtro.Valor,filtroInstancia);
}

public object ObtenerInstancia(string nombreClase)
{
     Type type = Type.GetType(nombreClase);
     if (type != null){
        var nuevoObjeto= 
        System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(string className)
       return nuevoObjeto;
     }

return null;
}

//asignar valor
 bool TryParse<T>(string source, out T value)
{
    TypeConverter converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof (T));
    if (converter.CanConvertTo(typeof (T)) && converter.CanConvertFrom(typeof (string)))
    {
        value = (T)converter.ConvertFromString(source);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        value = default (T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta! Voy a hacer una prueba y confirmo si me ha servido.